# CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView leaving empty space at the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

This is a basic model of my XML:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background_colour"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:id="@+id/profile_screen_appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:expandedTitleMarginTop="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="4dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="32dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                >

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:background="@color/fab_material_red_500"
                    >

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


             <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    >

  <!-- the ViewPager is programatically set to be have the height and width equivalent to that of the screen width of the device -->              <com.example.heavymagikhq.MyViewPager
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
                    />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/profile_info_recycler"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The problem**

At the moment some of the content in the `RecyclerView` is slightly off screen and I am able to reveal it by scrolling. The problem is that although only a slight amount of content is off screen the entire screen scrolls up until only the RecyclerView's content is showing at the top of the screen below the CollapsingToolbarLayout at a collapsed height equivalent to that of the Toolbar . I've tried adding `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` to the RecyclerView but this didn't solve the issue

**A Note**

When the CollapsingToolbarLayout's height is set to 625dp the screen doesn't scroll at all, but, when I set it to 626dp the content of the screen scrolls until the CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed to the height of a Toolbar, so this extra 1dp of height makes the screen go from not scrolling to scrolling much more than 1dp. The 625dp figure is presumably related to the device's (Nexus 7 2013) screen size. Also, regardless of what `minHeight` I set the CollapsingToolbarLayout to, the CollapsingToolbarLayout always collapses at the height equaivalent to a Toolbar's.

**My Question in a nutshell**

How can I make it so the screen only scrolls to reveal the content that is not on screen/beyond the content of the RecyclerView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

I found solution，you can set "minHeight" for AppBarLayout childView, and set app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"